# How do I get / available space with "df" and output it to a log file?

Tags: shell

With the command of `df`, I can get something like:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      197844228 15578648 180242500   8% /
devtmpfs         4101368        0   4101368   0% /dev
tmpfs             820648      292    820356   1% /run
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1693720        4   1693716   1% /run/shm
```

What if I just want to keep the *180242500* number recorded of `/` and store it in a file (like `disk-space-available.txt`)

If I use `df >> disk-space-available.txt` it will store all the content while I just want the raw number in that file.

For example if there is something like this then it's working:

```
df -OUTPUT=raw-available-number
180242500
```

What can I do?

Comment: `df | awk '$4 ~ /[[:digit:]]+/ { print $4 }' >> file`

Comment: this will get extra three lines of 0

Comment: Yeah, unless you clarify your question, we can't help more. It seem that you want only `/` available space right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter easily with `awk`, checking if the last field equal `/`, then print the corresponding `4th` field:

```
df | awk '$NF == "/" { print $4 }' >> output
```

or:

```
df / | awk 'NR == 2 { print $4 }' >> output
```

Answer (score 7):

With `df` from GNU coreutils:

```
$> df --output=avail /
Avail
12345
$> df --output=avail / | grep -v Avail
12345
```

Comment: Just a side note to say this is likely not portable to other *nixes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the GNU version of 'df', you can use 'stat' to get the number and size of the available blocks.

```
stat --file-system --format="%f %S" /
```

You can then multiply them together to get the bytes available.

```
(stat=$(stat --file-system --format="%f %S" /) && echo $(( ${stat/ /*} )))
```

You can optionally convert it to human readable with `numfmt --to=iec`.

Comment: Not portable because of stat --file-system, or some other reason? I'm using GNU coreutils' stat, which may be installable.